# Can I paint the exterior of a meter socket?

Tags: electrical, meter

My meter socket is on the front of my house in a prominent grey color against my home's tan brick exterior.

While it certainly makes a bold statement to the world that I am not part of an Amish community, I was wondering: Would it would violate code to tone it down a bit by painting the exterior of the meter socket enclosure to a color that better matches the brick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I wouldn't think painting the meter would violate electrical codes, as long as the paint doesn't damage the enclosure. You should **always** check with the utility, before doing anything to the meter.

You may or may not own the meter/enclosure, that depends on the utility. But you **definitely** don't want the utility to accuse you of meter tampering. If they say the paint somehow interferes with the meter, they could fine you and/or make you replace/repair it.

This is a question for the utility, not a bunch of numbnuts on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking about electrical code, no.  In most places, you own (and are responsible for) the meter box.  As long as the electric company is able to read the meter, there's no problem with painting it.  How to paint it is another question.

Comment: Ownership of the meter enclosure can be a gray area, it's best to check with the utility before doing anything.